# How do I NPM install package globally from private registry

Tags: npm

I have private npm registry `'A'`, and using .npmrc in my repo
.npmrc is

```
registry=A
```

then when I install axios like `npm i axios`, axios gotten from my `A` registry.
but when I install axios globally `npm i axios -g`, axios gotten from npm registry (`https://registry.npmjs.org/npm`)

how do i install package globally from my private registry?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up the registry for npm globally. Open a terminal and type

```
npm config set registry="<your-registry-address>"
```

After adding it you can check it with

```
npm config list
```

Or you can open directly the global `.npmrc` config at `C:\Users\you_user\`, if you already added something with `npm config set`. (The file is created when the first entry is added and removed when the last entry is deleted with `npm config delete <entry_for_delete>`).

Comment: thank you for your answer. but that affect `npm i <package>` only (It means installing at current path). 
  
is that config affect `npm i <package> -g`?

additionally I am using node,npm with nvm. and `npm config list` show `registry=A`

Comment: Please try `npm config set registry="<your-registry-address> --global`.
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-config.
At me `npm config set registry="<your-registry-address>"` set the global .npmrc, I think in your environment is something different.

Comment: In my case, `npm config set registry="<your-registry-address> --global` doesn't affect `npm i -g`. it affects only in `npm i` with no `per-project config file`, `per-user config file` environment. (config options are resolved in priority order) https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/npmrc . `npm config set registry="<your-registry-address> --global` affects `npm i -g` in your environment?